# Can't reach devices behind a router which is behind a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a similar network setup as the one in the given link.

[Network Diagram](https://superuser.com/questions/974896/connecting-two-networks-two-isps-two-routers-and-two-different-subnets)

The problem is, the **other router** devices and router itself cannot ping devices behind **my router**
and **my router** devices and router itselfcannot ping devices behind **other router**.

But **my router** can ping the **other router** and the **other router** can ping **my router**.

Please help me in the matter

**my router** is a TL-WR740N v5

**other router** is iBall W3GX150N

**spare router** is TD-W8968

Regards,

Darknet

Comment: why have you downvoted??

Comment: Sounds like you simply aren't allowing Ping through the routers.  Please edit your question and describe exactly how your network is wired/configured (especially in relation to the two routers), and what you've already done/attempted in getting this to work.  As-is there's not enough information here to give you an answer.

Comment: my router and spare router is connected with wds, spare router and other router is hardwired with other router lan going to spare router wan.nat and dhcp and firewall is disabled on spare router.

Comment: static routes on my router is destination:192.168.5.0 sm:255.255.255.0 gateway:192.168.1.1. other router destination:192.168.1.0 sm:255.255.255.0 gateway:192.168.5.10